# How to resolve generic type inheritance with Unity IoC

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm new in DI and IoC and I have an interface resolution problem.

Techno: WPF, C#, Unity Container

I try to show generic grid dynamically via models type, those will define the resolution of the right service to call when I filter data in it. I do this because the project I'm landing on has almost +100 business objects. I won't create a view/viewmodel/interface for each one.

So, in models i have for example: CustomerModel / OrderModel / ...
In my services: CustomerService and ICustomerService / OrderService and IOrderService / ... and all of my services inherit also from IBaseService where T is a model.
Like this:

```
//For the service call
public interface IBaseService<TModel>
{
    Task<IEnumerable<TModel>> GetWithFilter(string filterQuery);
}

public interface ICustomerService : IBaseService<CustomerModel>
{
    IEnumerable<CustomerModel> Get(string filterQuery);
    //...
}

public class CustomerService : ICustomerService
{
    // Inherit form IBaseService<TModel>
    public IEnumerable<CustomerModel> GetWithFilter(string filterQuery)
    {
        return Get(filterQuery); //
    }

    // Inherit from ICustomerService
    public IEnumerable<CustomerModel> Get(string filterQuery = null)
    {
        // some code
        // return IEnumerable<CustomerModel>
    }
}

//A part of the generic ViewModel
public class UC_GridViewModel<TModel> : BaseViewModel, IUC_GridViewModel<TModel>
{

    private IBaseService<TModel> _modelService;
    public IBaseService<TModel> ModelService
    {
        get { return _modelService; }
        set { Set(ref _modelService, value); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<TModel> _sourceItem;
    public ObservableCollection<TModel> SourceItem
    {
        get { return _sourceItem; }
        set { Set(ref _sourceItem, value); }
    }

    [InjectionConstructor]
    public UC_GridViewModel(IEnumerable<TModel> sourceItem, IBaseService<TModel> modelService)
    {
        _sourceItem = new ObservableCollection<TModel>(sourceItem);
        _modelService = modelService;
    }

    // This is called by a command
    public void FilterGridCommand(string filterQuery)
    {
        _sourceItem = _modelService.GetWithFilter(filterQuery);
    }

}

//In IoC Container (Resolver layer bind to Unity Container)
DependencyResolver.RegisterType(typeof(IBaseService<CustomerModel>), typeof(CustomerService));
DependencyResolver.RegisterType<ICustomerService, CustomerService>();
DependencyResolver.RegisterType(typeof(IUC_GridViewModel<>), typeof(UC_GridViewModel<>));
```

What I Except:
If I instantiate a UC_GridViewModel I get a ModelService from type CustomerService that will perform inherited method from IBaseService.

When I run my solution I got that:
`` ResolutionFailedException: Resolution failed with error: No public constructor is available for type API_Caller.IBaseService`1 ``

`` InvalidOperationException: No public constructor is available for type API_Caller.IBaseService`1[BO_Models.CustomerModel]. ``

So how to resolve my IBaseService in this case to avoid those errors ?

Comment: I would try commenting your first registertype. You should just register icustomerservice as customerservice.  As you've not registered customermodel you will probably also need a ParameterOverrides in your resolve. But i'd rather customerservice didn't need any parameter to know it's all about customers.

Comment: Hello Andy, thanks for your answer.
It works if I remove first line (wrong typing) and register every type I use:
    DependencyResolver.RegisterType<IBaseService<CustomerModel>, CustomerService>();
        DependencyResolver.RegisterType<IBaseService<OrderModel>, OrderService>();
    ...
I alos tried to inherit all services from an abstract BaseCaller<TModel> : IBaseCaller<TModel> and register like this:
DependencyResolver.RegisterType(typeof(IBaseService<>), typeof(BaseService<>));
But it doesn't work too despit what I read on web, an answer ?

Comment: Does a customer service every really return anything other than a customer model though?